# CSS full page width header

Tags: header

Hey I have a little problem I have a full page header but when I zoom in or reduce the screen size and slide along. It is not full page width it just leaves white space. May css code goes a follow.

```
.header {
background:#242424 repeat-x;
color:#ffffff;
width:100%;
height:74px;
font-family: 'Karla', cursive;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
```

}

Comment: Why are you setting the width? If it is a `div` or other block-level element it should already expand to the width of (its containing element).

Comment: Try removing the `width:100%;` line. If that doesn't work, you'll need to post your html structure, and more of the css

Comment: Removing the width does not do anything :/ and the html is just <div class="header"></div> and that is all the css I removed the inside of the did to work out the problem.

Comment: Pretty sure you are misunderstanding. We need to see the structure of your page, all the way to the `body` tag. And any CSS that would affect any of the parent elements of this div. If it is like you said, you wouldn't have a problem as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/y7fPq/

Comment: It's not the children of `.header` that are affecting it. It is the parents. Isolating down to `.header` only will not give us enough information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by your `<div class="medium-cont"></div>` tag.

You are setting its width to 1400px in CSS which is causing the problem.

You don't need to use this element, instead set the background image of `.medium-back`.

```
<div class="medium-back">
    <div class="register"></div>
    <div class="medium-cont"></div> <!-- Remove this line -->
</div>
```

Change your `.medium-back` style to this:

```
.medium-back {
    background: #19D89B url(images/medium-content.png) no-repeat;
    height: 475px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Then remove any other `width:100%;` styles you have on the outermost elements.